# Amazon web services remote mysql access denied for 'user'@'localhost' ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, remote-access

Need help!
i've set remote permissions for mysql (port 3306 both inbound and outbound ) from my ec2 instnce security groups settings, 
set wildcard privileges (%) for the user in mysql database, 
set bind-address=0.0.0.0 
in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file 
still cant connect to mysql from my remote host.

mysql version 5.7
ubuntu 16.04 server.

Answer (score 1):

For mysql version 5.7 and above use /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
For mysql version 5.6 and below only use /etc/mysql/my.cnf

if there's a firewall installed, you should open the port on the firewall and restart

```
ufw allow 3306/tcp
sudo service ufw restart
```

It's not secure way to connect mysql remotely. It it's more secure if can connect to MySQL through ssh tunnel.

Please follow the steps in the link below to get remote access to MySQL -
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: i ran this in terminal:
`sudo ufw status`
**Status: inactive**
i guess there is no default firewalls installed in t2 medium instances as i haven't installed one yet.
although i tried  allowing custom tcp rule for port 3306 for both inbound and outbound connections from security group settings, didn't helped yet! :( 
anyways thanks for answering.

Comment: For mysql version 5.7 and above use /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
bind-address  = 0.0.0.0

For mysql version 5.6 and below only use /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: thanks this totally solved the problem , editing the mysqld.cnf fixed the problem. looks like i was roaming around in the wrong directory allday :)

Comment: @MilonHossain i edited the answer, if it helped you plz add +1 so it can help others :)